# Get a UID primary key before inserting in database

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net

I am creating user profiles (javascript webpage) that I store in a SQL database

Those profiles have a primary key `ID` that has auto increment feature.

When the user is creating its profile, he has to upload a file.

I'd like this file to be named id.ext, the problem is I upload the file through ajax during the creation of the profile, before the profile is saved in database as the user need to profide information about this file in order for the profile to be acceptable.

I could retried the `max(id)` in database and use it during my ajax upload but if 2 people are creating a profile at the same time : problem.

I've come up with other solutions :

- naming the file `bigrandom.ext` and storing this name in database, but my boss absolutely wants `id.ext`
- creating blank profile with an "uncomplete" flag + date at upload and run a batch each month to delete uncomplete entries in database
- upload with id.ext, if the file already exist, name it id+1.ext and inform the webpage through json message in return of the POST query

As I think it's a common problem I guess there is some best practices about this, maybe even a feature from SQL I don't know.

Comment: What DBMS (brand and version) are you using? Is the file being stored in the database as a LOB, or as a physical file somewhere of the web server? Does your server-side code have the ability to rename a file immediately after it is uploaded?

Comment: For now the file are stored physically and the DBMS is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 but everything has been created in order to be able to switch physical<->blob and to change the DBMS so I would feel guilty using a proprietary trick

Comment: @IggY You're arguably handling this on a completely wrong level. You shouldn't care about the DBs IDs in *your* code. If you want to use that ID for other things (like the filename), your best bet really is to create a dummy row (in a transaction if you know how to do that safely) and use that ID. Separating the DB ID from the filesystem name is preferrable (although there's some maintainability arguments in favour of using the DB ID). GUIDs work decently as random file names, even though they are somewhat long. Do not *guess* at the ID - `max(Id) + 1` is not safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [sequence object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) in the DBMS is far safer and more robust than taking your chances with `MAX(id) +1`. MS SQL Server has supported sequences since SQL Server 2012, and other database platforms have had them for an even longer time.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a Guid field in the Table and create it when uploading the image. it will be unque always. U can save the image with this Guid as name.